# Putty Serial, Edit file via vi or vim

Tags: linux, terminal, vim, putty

I am trying to connect to my single board computer terminal, which has OpenWRT Linux. in order to do that, I connect the board serial pin (UART) to my pc and access to the terminal using Putty. I need to modify some network configuration file.

> 1- I only have vi or vim editor on my Linux.
>   2- I cannot install any other editor using package manager because I do not have access to the **internet** and also my **USB** port.

there are some tutorials on the net that introduced some commands but they are not working for putty in serial mode.

for example, vi can be opened in 2 modes, **command mode** and **edit mode**
I can go to edit mode by typing `i` and exit from this mode by `Esc` key. but I cannot save the modifications.

Comment: The TERM variable might be set wrong. Other than that you can use sed to edit single lines or simply copy and paste the new file into `cat >file.new` and rename it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer :

1-If you are currently in insert or append mode, press Esc.
2-Press `:` (colon). The cursor should reappear at the lower left corner of the screen beside a colon prompt.
3-Enter the following:

> wq

then press `enter`

Comment: Or use ':x' instead of ':wq'. It's shorter and does bothe, save and quit.

Comment: Or use just `:w` if you want to save without quitting.